# Electron Builder: Not allowed to load local resource: app.asar/build/index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have an issue when using electron builder I got blank page and error in console:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/emretekince/Desktop/DCSLogBook/client/dist/win-unpacked/resources/app.asar/build/index.html

main.js

```js
const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/build/index.html'),
  protocol: 'file:',
  slashes: true
});
mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);
```

Comment: Any restricting options when initializing the BrowserWindow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved by adding "files" in package.json

```
"files": [
  "*.js",
  "build",
  "node_modules"
],
```

Comment: This is not worked for me. what the `files` actually do?

Comment: How do you know what to add to "files"?

Comment: Where should I add the Files? I have added it to my package.json.But no change, the error persists

Comment: I used this as well as moving my html file into the static folder. So I just added "static" to the list inside of "files".

Answer (score 5):

I think your index.html file is not present in your given location. `__dirname, '/build/index.html'`

I missed this silly point and wasted a lot of time. Angular-cli creates default location for index.html inside a folder in dist.

```
dist/project-name/index.html
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried to fix this my whole day & finally found the solution,

```
"build": {
"appId": "myledgerapp",
"extends": null,
"files": [
  "./build/**/*",
  "./public/electron.js"
]}
```

We need to add files in build section where electron.js is my entry point.

Comment: @Akashxoloti, but what does 'files' do if included?

Comment: @Vass I think It may including above mentioned files into app.asar. which is placed inside dist/resources

Answer (score 4):

I got a similar problem and was missing the `path.join`:

Bad Code:

```
win.loadFile('index.html')
```

Fixed Code:

```
win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and managed to sort it out using:

`path.resolve('index.html')`

like this:

`const startUrl = path.resolve('index.html');
mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);`

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue i placed the below line before loading the file.

```
 window.webContents.openDevTools()
```

Example Code

```
// Issue code
window =  new BrowserWindow({width:800,height:600,parent:mainWindow})
window.webContents.openDevTools()
window.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname,'/../views/file.html'),
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true
}))

// Issue Solved code
window =  new BrowserWindow({width:800,height:600,parent:mainWindow})

window.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname,'/../views/file.html'),
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true
}))
window.webContents.openDevTools()
```